How to migrate conditional field formatting to different Org?
Salesforce has newly introduced ConditionalFieldFormatting feature in the winter 25 release. I have implemented that to my project. But during migration to a different sandbox via workbench I encountered an Error.
Error: the ruleset I have created and is on the flexi page cannot be found. In the package I have included the object as part of the metadata but workbench was unable to retrieve the meta related to it. (Not the exact words)
So, I researched on how I can do that and I then found following salesforce documents:-

Conditional Field Formatting in Lightning App Builder: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=platform.conditional_formatting_overview.htm&type=5
UiFormatSpecificationSet: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_uiformatspecificationset.htm

Form the 2nd link I found the name of the metadata that I can use in the package to retrieve conditional field formatting for a particular field using its ruleset name.
Metadata:

Sentiment_Score
UiFormatSpecificationSet

where Sentiment_Score is ruleset name which is applied on a field.
But after taking the retrieve with the metadata mentioned above using workbench the zip file is not able to get the required metadata hence failed to do migration.
Let me know if there is a solution that I can use to migrate.
This is my first post on StackExchange let me know you need any more info. Thanks.

Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  Is your target sandbox on Winter 25?

Hi @DavidCheng, Yes the target org is on Winter 25. Thought I was not able to do migration I have done the changes manually in the target org.

are you running workbench using api version 62? is your package.xml that you use for retrieve and deploy at v62?  I've successfully deployed UiFormatSpecificationSet at v62 using Gearset (a devops vendor product) and it uses the MDAPI so this can definitely be done

Hi @cropredy,
I was able to successfully deploy the package to a different org as well. The issue was with the package.xml file. The package was set to version 61, and the UiFormatSpecificationSet is not supported in that version, which prevented the metadata from being retrieved. I updated the version to 62, and everything worked as expected! Thanks for pointing that out.

In order to deploy UiFormatSpecificationSet, you need to be sure that the metadata api version you are using is at least V62.0 as this metadata type was introduced in Winter 25
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Sentiment_Score</members>
        <name>UiFormatSpecificationSet</name>
    </types>
    <version>62.0</version>    <======= V62.0 or higher !
</Package>

